# Is there an equivalent to Microsoft SQL's isnull() function in PHP?

Tags: php

In tSQL there's a great little function called [isnull()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), which takes the following:

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

I know about [is_null()](http://www.php.net/is_null) in PHP, but it's no the same. Is there another function I'm missing?

I can see it being useful in cases like this one (assume the isnull() here would work the same as tSQL):

```
die("Function does not exist" . isnull($_POST['function'], ". No function was specified"));
```

Comment: are you trying to find out if the value of $_POST['function'] is an actual function in your application or just trying to make sure $_POST['function'] is set? Maybe you just need a ternary: `$var = isset($_POST['function']) ? $_POST['function'] : 'default value';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest you could get to an [`isnull`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function in PHP would be using [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) and the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$val = isset($val) ? $val : $value_if_val_is_null;
```